# WPF Data bound ProgressBar not showing progress

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, progress-bar

I am having troubles with getting the ProgressBar working.

XAML:

```
    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="590"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    ProgressBar.DataContext = progressModel;
```

IProgressModel:

```
public interface IProgressModel
{
    double Minimum { get; set; }
    double Maximum { get; set; }
    double Progress { get; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
    private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        Minimum = 0;
        Maximum = RenamableFiles.Count;

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var renamableFile in RenamableFiles)
        {
            var oldFilename = ReCreateOldFileName(renamableFile);
            var renameProposalFilename = CreateNewFileName(renamableFile);

            if (oldFilename != null && renameProposalFilename != null && !oldFilename.Equals(renameProposalFilename))
            {
                // File.Move(oldFilename, renameProposalFilename);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Progress = i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the pretty straight forward PropertyChanged mechanism:

```
    private double _progress;
    public double Progress 
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set 
        { 
            _progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The ProgressBar starts "full" and remains that way throughout the process. I have read all related threads on SO, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing `WorkerOnDoWork` runs on a thread other than the UI thread. If that's the case, I don't think this is very safe, since you'll have two threads accessing the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind your maximum, too:

```
    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" 
        Value="{Binding Progress}" 
        Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" 
        Minimum="{Binding Minimum}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="10,35,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="590"/>
```

Comment: pfffff... that took me an hour :). maybe I should post a question earlier next time. thx a million! (will accept when SO allows me to)

Comment: @Reed, Maximum/Minimum are auto properties.  Why is UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged if the source is doing the pumping and the view doesn't need to push???  And there's no setters to answer the push anyway?

Comment: @GarryVass That's the interface, not the implementation - I was assuming that they aren't autoproperties, and implement INotifyPropertyChanged, just like the current value.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, +1 now it's right.  There's nothing happening in the view that requires an update to the source.  Thanks for the speedy reply too!